# How to on scroll header?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to fix the problem in my code where I can't scroll the content with the header fixed. So please help me out with some guidance.

**This is the Javascript code**

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var w3-third = document.getElementsById("myw3-third");
var sticky = w3-third.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    w3-third.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    w3-third.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

Header part of my code.

I want this part to be fixed and body content to be scrolled.

```html
<!--starting of header-->
<div class="w3-third" id="myw3-third">
  <div class="logoimg">
    <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="logo image">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="w3-third">
  <div class="menubar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">BOOKING</a>
        <li><a href="#">PHARMACY</a>
          <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="w3-third">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">SIGN IN </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">SIGN UP </button>
  </div>
</div>
<!--end of header-->
```

Comment: instead of `sticky` did you try `fixed` property?

Comment: Try to use ```outerHeight``` instead of offsetTop.
And in CSS file you have to add ```.sticky{position: fixed; width:100%;top:0;left:0}```

Comment: I got it thank you

Comment: You can follow this link [Sticky header](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sticky_header)